# How do I detect asynchronous events in kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Here is my problem:
One processor in kafka have to triggered by an asynchronous event,can i source the asynchronous events into global store,and update them into global store,the processor look up global store?
Is this a bad idea?Is there some synchronous problems?Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Kafka is asynchronous on its own

Comment: What i mean is that can not join another source,because both of two are not related by any key

Comment: You should edit your question to include these details then. Can you use Kafka Streams to select the key from the value, at all? Otherwise, sounds like you'll need to create a keying system

Comment: Not exactly,What i need is enrich data in my processor with some unrelated with external data use global store!

Comment: Kafka Steams doesn't stop you from doing external lookups